# What is the etymology of the saying "talk is cheap"?

Tags: etymology

Google Ngram lists the first usage at around 1810 but a [later book](http://books.google.com/books?id=wITnAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22&pg=PA227#v=onepage&q=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22&f=false) refers to it as an old [saw](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=saw).

Is there any way to know what the original context of this saying was? I understand that it probably goes along with the idea that [actions are stronger than words](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=actions%20are%20stronger%20than%20words&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) or that [actions are greater than words](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=actions%20are%20greater%20than%20words&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) but I can't verify that.

I am curious where it was first popularized and maybe even the context that lead it to be coined in the first place.

Comment: I think an ant or a cockroach might say something like that.

Comment: @Billare What do you mean?

Comment: @logicbird, I think this has to do with your title, *entomology* being the science studying insects and *etymology* that of the origin of words.

Comment: lol, +1 for not accepting spell check suggestions at a glance. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: Sam Spade: "Ten thousand? We were talking about a lot more money than this."
Kasper Gutman: "Yes, sir, we were, but this is genuine coin of the realm. With a dollar of this, you can buy ten dollars of talk."

Comment: Speech is silver but silence is golden?

Answer (score 3):

The Facts on File [Dictionary of Proverbs](http://books.google.com/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&lpg=PA259&dq=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22%20origin&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22%20origin&f=false) has the following (emphasis mine):

> **talk is cheap**: [...] "What can you do?" "Go out Montana, just as soon as the weather is fit, and relocate the mine..." "Talk is cheap, but it takes money to pay for railroad tickets, went on Malone" (Horatio Alger, *Joe the Hotel Boy*, 1906)  The proverb was first recorded in its current form in **1843** (T.C. Haliburton, *Attaché*), but the sentiment it expresses is of earlier origin.

Here is the relevant quotation from Haliburton's book, completely titled *The Attaché; or, Sam Slick in England,* and courtesy of [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/7823/7823-h/7823-h.htm):

> "Minister," said Mr. Slick, "come, cheer up, it makes me kinder dismal to hear you talk so. When Captain McKenzie hanged up them three free and enlightened citizens of ours on board of the—Somers—he gave 'em three cheers. We are worth half a dozen dead men yet, so cheer up. Talk to these friends of ourn, they might think you considerable starch if you don't talk, and **talk is cheap**, it don't cost nothin' but breath, a scrape of your hind leg, and a jupe of the head, that's a fact.

Haliburton was a novelist, and Sam Slick seems to have been his primary literary foil, much like Hercule Poirot and Tom Ripley became for Agatha Christie and Patricia Highsmith, respectively.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Slick) (emphasis mine):

> Sam Slick was a character created by Thomas Chandler Haliburton, a Canadian judge and author. With his wry wit and Yankee voice, Sam Slick of Slicksville put forward his views on "human nature" in a regular column in the Novascotian, beginning in 1835. The twenty-one sketches were published in a collection titled *The Clockmaker, or the Sayings and Doings of Samuel Slick of Slicksville,* First Series in 1836, supplemented by an additional 12 unpublished or new sketches. **The book was Canada's first international bestseller and was hugely popular, not only in Nova Scotia but also in Britain and the United States**....Slick’s wise-cracking commentary on the colonial life of Nova Scotia and relations with the U.S. and Britain struck a note with readers, leading to a second series in 1838 and a third in 1840.

The opening paragraph from a biography of Haliburton, titled *[Inventing Sam Slick: a biography of Thomas Chandler Haliburton](http://books.google.com/books?id=BiO988RMW-0C&lpg=PP1&dq=sam%20slick%20in%20england&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=sam%20slick%20in%20england&f=false)*, gives one a clue to Slick's renown:

> For fifty years after 1837, Sam Slick the Clockmaker was the most
>   celebrated literary Yankee of the day.  The mere mention of him
>   brought smiles to the faces of readers in Victorian Britain.
>   He struck the funny bone of a nation with his barrage of Yankee slang.
>   Few readers knew that his creator, Thomas Chandler Haliburton,
>   was a gentleman, a Judge of the Inferior Court of Common Please
>   in the colony of Nova Scotia.  Today, Sam Slick is still more famous
>   than his creator.

So our best guess should be that the sentiment **talk is cheap** spread in its current form as a result of being associated with a long past literary phenomenon in Sam Slick, whose turn of phrase — perhaps even including *talk is cheap* — seemed to have delighted those over the pond.

Comment: This answers the popularization part nicely, but the _Facts on File_'s "first recorded" date is disproved by the OP's 1810 reference.

Answer (score 2):

An earlier iteration of this was *words are cheap*.

This phrase I found back to a 1769 [publication](http://books.google.com/books?id=B5lVAAAAYAAJ&q=words%20are%20cheap#v=snippet&q=words%20are%20cheap&f=false) of collected works of John Bunyan (of *The Pilgrim's Progress* fame) in an essay titled *The Saint's Knowledge of Christ's Love* which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Bunyan#Works) has penned in 1692:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=B5lVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA456&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2tKRlgufRGkah5gqxbG4smfwn1MA&ci=184%2C1245%2C800%2C64&edge=0]

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty straight-forward one and could have been around long before it made an appearance in print.

Anyway, somehow you have mixed up the books/dates.  The first occurrence in ngrams is [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=s9URAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22&hl=en&ei=2POzTaWZDoGp8AOwqNGVDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22talk%20is%20cheap%22&f=false) in 1810 where the author is saying that false patriotism consists of ostentatious expressions, whereas the true patriot can be recognised by his deed.

Comment: I updated the question in response to my mix up that you pointed out. I guess I'm still getting the hang of using ngrams.